# Javascript: For loop, progressive numbers with same digits

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the misunderstanding title, I don't know how could explain better.

That's my problem: I have this loop

```
for(i=1; i<1000; i++){
     "MyName_"+i;
}
```

This will give the following

```
MyName_1
MyName_2
...
MyName_10
...
MyName_100
```

How can I do, in a easy way, to have the same number of digits anytime?
This means

```
MyName_001
...
MyName_010
...
MyName_100
```

obviously without doing stuff like

```
if(i<10)
...
if((i>10)&&(i<100))
```

because the input number is a input so it may be 1000, 10000 or 10000000 and I don't want to write tons of "if()"...

Thank you

Comment: Lots of duplicates: [`[javascript] zero pad number`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+zero+pad+number)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript **[`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** method

```js
var input = 100; //input any number
var len = input.toString().length;
for (i = 1; i < input; i++) {
  console.log("MyName_" + ('000000000000000' + i).slice(-len));
}
```

Comment: what, no https://github.com/stevemao/left-pad ? :)

Comment: What if instead of 100, there will be 1000?

Comment: @PranavCBalan, not convinced. Why you are hard-coding '000'? For example, when i will be 100, still you are adding '000'. Actually it should add only '0'

Comment: @VicJordan: The `.slice(-4)` part is important. It returns the last four characters of the string. The last four characters of `"000100"` are `"0100"`.

Comment: @VicJordan :  even `1000` the code will works : `for (i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  console.log(
    "MyName_" + ('00' + i).slice(-3)
  )
}` , I just reduced it because the stacksnippet console library not shows that much element...